# OIDC - correct signin flow for js client

Tags: javascript, openid-connect

I have an app build with Vue.js and I am trying to implement an OIDC client. But, I am not sure if I understand the flow completely. I have been following an example app for [OIDC Vue client](https://github.com/joaojosefilho/vuejsOidcClient), where in [SecurityService](https://github.com/joaojosefilho/vuejsOidcClient/blob/master/src/services/SecurityService.js), method `getSignedIn` is called that checks if `user` exists and calls `signIn` method if there is no `user`. In `signIn` method `OIDC client` method `signinRedirect` is called which returns `user` from a promise:

```
  // Check if there is any user logged in
  getSignedIn () {
    let self = this
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      mgr.getUser().then(function (user) {
        if (user == null) {
          self.signIn()
          return resolve(false)
        } else{
          return resolve(true)
        }
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return reject(err)
      });
    })
  }

  // Redirect of the current window to the authorization endpoint.
  signIn () {
    mgr.signinRedirect().catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

I have tried to implement the same thing in my service class `AuthService`:

```
const usermanager = oidc.getOidcUserManager();

export default class AuthService {

    // Check if there is any user logged in
    getSignedIn () {
        let self = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            usermanager.getUser().then(function (user) {
                if (user === null) {
                    self.signinRedirect();
                    return resolve(false);
                } else{
                    return resolve(true);
                }
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject(err);
            });
        })
    }

    // Redirect of the current window to the authorization endpoint.
    signIn() {
        usermanager.signinRedirect().catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Then, if I call this in my `App.vue` in `created` method:

```
    data: () => ({
        authService: new AuthService(),
    }),
    created() {
        this.authService.getSignedIn();
```

I get the **error** below in the **console**, and the app keeps refreshing in the browser in the loop constantly:

```
UserManager.getUser: user not found in storage
```

If I use **OIDC client manager** `signinRedirectCallback` method instead of `signinRedirect`, like this:

```
    // Redirect of the current window to the authorization endpoint.
    signIn() {
        usermanager.signinRedirectCallback().catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Then I get the error from the `Promise`:

```
Error: No matching state found in storage
```

What is the right way to implement this, and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your client is redirecting the browser to the OP (OIDC Provider), the user is authenticating successfully and then redirecting the browser back to your client.

Your client needs to call `userManager.signinRedirectCallback()` when the OP redirects back to the client. That will take the tokens and create a user.

If you don't create the user `usermanager.getUser()` is going to return null and you'll start another authorization attempt, this time the OP is going to have a valid session so instead of logging in it's just instantly redirecting back to the client with new tokens which the client ignores and round and round the loop it goes.